# What is a shortcut to select columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am using this dataset
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD
And I want to select only 'Country Name','Country Code', 'Indicator Name' ,'Indicator Code', and the last 10 years columns.
so this is the code that I wrote

```
GDP[['Country Name','Country Code','Indicator Name','Indicator Code','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020']]
```

Is there any shortcut?

Comment: Slice and [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) together the two slices? `GDP[GDP.columns[:4].union(GDP.columns[-11:], sort=False)]`. Or just unpack `GDP[[*GDP.columns[:4], *GDP.columns[-11:]]]`?

Comment: You could use column index but it is not cause issues if columns are re-arranged. Instead you create a list of column names and pass the list to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a shortcut but at least is readable:

```
keys = ['Country Name','Country Code','Indicator Name','Indicator Code']
years = [str(i) for i in range(2010,2021)]
keys.append(years )
GDP[keys]
```